# Does `@dependabot recreate` also rebase onto latest mainline?

Tags: dependabot

I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer to this, so asking here:

On GitHub projects that use Dependabot, will `@dependabot recreate` also rebase the branch onto latest mainline just like `@dependabot rebase` does? Or does it just simply recreate the branch from the same commit that the branch was currently based off of?

Bonus point: Where are the docs that clarify this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `recreate` will not only "recreated" but also "rebase".

See also this GitHub issue: [dependabot-core#6204](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/6204)

as the author of the issue mentioned (he is currently working at GitHub):

> The only difference between `recreate` and `rebase` is that `rebase` fails if there are any additional commits in the branch, while `recreate` skips that check.

Comment: Really sucks that there isn't a more official place that this command difference is being documented. But anyway, thanks for pointing me in this direction.